# republishing a Gazebo topic to a ROS topic

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently working on trying to get a gazebo topic into the ROS topic list so I can access it through the matlab interface with ROS.

Right now  I managed to create a subscriber to the gazebo topic in question (gazebo/default/physics/contacts) but I can't figure out exactly what type of ROS message it is to allow me to publish it again in ROS.

Here is the code:

```
import trollius
from trollius import From

import pygazebo
import pygazebo.msg.contacts_pb2
@trollius.coroutine
def publish_loop():
    manager = yield From(pygazebo.connect()) 

    def callback(data):
        message = pygazebo.msg.contacts_pb2.Contacts.FromString(data)
        print(message)

    subscriber = manager.subscribe('/gazebo/default/physics/contacts',
                     'gazebo.msgs.Contacts',
                     callback)

    yield From(subscriber.wait_for_connection())
    while(True):
        yield From(trollius.sleep(1.00))
        print('wait...')
    print(dir(manager))
    import logging
    
    logging.basicConfig()
    
    loop = trollius.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(publish_loop())
```

So, my problem could be solved in two ways:

1. Figuring out a way to find the corresponding essage type in ROS to publish it.
2. Figuring out a simpler way to do what i want to do.

Currently I'm working on both possibilities but I'm having a hard time...

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280631/republishing-a-gazebo-topic-to-a-ros-topic/) by [wonwon0](https://answers.ros.org/users/33404/wonwon0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have implemented a ros package that subscribes to gazebo and publishes a custom message with the wanted info. I use the transport library provided by gazebo.
https://github.com/wonwon0/gazebo_contact_republisher
Thank you for your input it made me rethink about my whole approach.

---

Originally posted by [wonwon0](https://answers.ros.org/users/33404/wonwon0/) with karma: 73 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-30**:
As this has solved your problem *for you*, I've made your answer the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but I believe that *if* there are specific messages that could mirror the Gazebo message structures they would be in [gazebo_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_msgs). Message/service documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/gazebo_msgs/html/index-msg.html).

For `/gazebo/default/physics/contacts` that could probably be the [ContactsState](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/gazebo_msgs/html/msg/ContactsState.html) message (but you'd have to verify that).

I'm again unsure, but aren't those already published as ROS messages by Gazebo, if you load have the [gazebo_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros) plugins?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wonwon0](https://answers.ros.org/users/33404/wonwon0/) on 2018-01-24**:
thank you for your answer, I will look into the documentation you provided. I am new to ROS and gazebo so maybe my problem is just a misunderstanding of the tools at my disposal.

Anyway, I will post an update if I figure what is my error.

How may I verify that I started gazebo_ros and not gazebo?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
You can probably start here: [wiki/gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs).

Note: `gazebo_ros` is a package, *not* a different version of Gazebo. It just integrates Gazebo with ROS. In some ways similar to what you have done with your Python script.

**Comment by [wonwon0](https://answers.ros.org/users/33404/wonwon0/) on 2018-01-24**:
I see what you are talking about. But I actually have some gazebo topics in the ros topics list. The thing is I dont see all the topics listed in gazebo topic list. gazebo/default/physics/contacts is one of the topics i dont see published in the ros topics. All the example only use the basic topics.